# modify image to black text on white background

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, pytorch, image-segmentation

I have an image that need to do OCR (Optical Character Recognition) to extract all data.

[image]

First I want to convert color image to black text on white background in order to improve OCR  accuracy.

I try below code

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("data7.png")
img.convert("1").save("result.jpg")
```

it gave me below unclear image

[image]

I expect to have this image

[image]

Then, I will use pytesseract to get a dataframe

```
import pytesseract as tess
file = Image.open("data7.png")
text = tess.image_to_data(file,lang="eng",output_type='data.frame')
text
```

Finally,the dataframe I want to get like below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a vanilla Pillow solution. Just grayscaling the image gives us *okay* results, but the green text is too faint.

So, we first scale the green channel up (sure, it might clip, but that's not a problem here), then grayscale, invert and auto-contrast the image.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

img = Image.open('rqDRe.png').convert('RGB')

r, g, b = img.split()

img = Image.merge('RGB', (
    r,
    g.point(lambda i: i * 3),  # brighten green channel
    b,
))

img = ImageOps.autocontrast(ImageOps.invert(ImageOps.grayscale(img)), 5)

img.save('rqDRe_processed.png')
```

### output

[image]

Comment: Hi AKX  text = tess.image_to_data(file,lang="eng",output_type='data.frame')
  doesn't give me the good result, the Date column is not recognized, any recommendation ?

Answer (score 3):

Converting RGB image to a binary image using [`PIL.Image.convert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) resulted with an "unclear" image due to the default [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither). In your case you do not want to dither at all:

```py
img.convert("1", dither=Image.Dither.NONE)
```

Will give you a clean conversion:

[image]

You still need to figure out how to capture the text in colors, but the noise is gone once you turn off dithering.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the background color by looking at the most prominent color while measuring the input image statistics with Torchvision.

More specifically you can use [`torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor.html):

```
>>> img = Image.open("test.png")
>>> tensor = TF.to_tensor(img)
```

Extract background color:

```
>>> u, c = tensor.flatten(1).unique(dim=1, return_counts=True)
>>> bckg = u[:,c.argmax()]
tensor([0.1216, 0.1216, 0.1216])
```

Get the mask of background:

```
>>> mask = (tensor.permute(1,2,0) == bckg).all(dim=-1)
```

Convert back to PIL with [`torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image.html)

```
>>> res = TF.to_pil_image(mask.float())
```

[image]

Then you can extract the data frame using [Python tesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/):

```
>>> text = tess.image_to_data(res, lang="eng", output_type='data.frame')
```

---

<sup>Using `from PIL import Image` 

and `import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF`</sup>

Comment: indeed the right way to tackle this. However, it is important to know the source of the "noise" when using PIL to convert to binary image - that is, the _dithering_ PIL uses by default. See my answer for details.